# how to DNS configure Android Emulator in Mac IOS?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I make a application. whose download data from server. it's work proper on device. but, in My system Android Emulator not working.
 Emulator have not internet Connection. how i configure, Please Help me.

I use Titanium Studio.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

In Table 1.  See the row labelled 'Network'.  This contains the flags you need to specify in order to configure the emulator to work on your own network/DNS/proxy etc.

If you are using Eclipse you can configure this in your run time settings, otherwise specify these flags in your script that starts the emulator/command line.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

I notice you're not using Eclipse, sorry I misread before.  Wherever you start your emulator, you need to specify the network settings using the command-line flags.  For example:

```
emulator -dns-server 12.34.5.6.78
```

Or

```
emulator -http-proxy http://proxy.example.com:8080
```

These flags can usually be configured in your IDE if your IDE supports integrated Android Emulator.

Comment: i am not understanding, what is doing this?
plz, u can clarify step by step?

Comment: In order for the Android emulator to access the network successfully, you need to specify your network settings (like you would in your Internet browser).  So you need to specify your network settings to the emulator.  How do you start your emulator?  In command-line you would do something like: 'emulator -dns-server 12.34.56.78' or 'emulator -http-proxy http://proxy.example.com:8080'

Comment: that is okey,but my problems is where i execute?
<emulator -dns-server 12.34.5.6.78>

Comment: In the command-line/terminal, wherever your emulator is started.  Or set the flags in your IDE wherever the emulator is configured.